# Android Studio fails to import my Eclipse Projects, either directly or as Gradle project

Tags: android, eclipse, import, gradle, android-studio

I have a workspace for Eclipse Luna, it contains 8 projects and it builds without any problem. I have tried exporting the primary project as a Gradle project and then opening that with Android Studio and I have also tried importing the primary project directly into Android Studio. 
I've verified that I have the latest versions of everything, Eclipse and AS but it doesn't make any difference.
The resulting project will not build. I get almost 100 build errors trying to build in Android Studio. I've wasted days trying to use this product, I've reported multiple IDE errors that occur during import to Google and feel like I'm going in circles.

If I import the exported build.gradle file, it complains that version 1.1.0 is required. Current version is 2.2.1

What information do I need to supply to help resolve this?

Comment: Definitely don't export to gradle and import. In recent versions you are supposed to import directly. But I know you said you tried that but maybe posting the build errors you got we could help you fix those.

Comment: Go ahead and let me know what build errors you are getting. That may help us figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your gradle build passes.

`gradle build`

or with a little bit help in Eclipse using http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/ Gradle for Eclipse plugin.